# True test of value type's default value?

Tags: c#, iequalitycomparer

In C#, how to properly check if a value type's value is truly default? In other words: whether all the elements are zero, as specified by the language?

Using `x == default` requires for the struct to define an equality comparer, which could be implemented as anything. Using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, default)` also allows the struct to override the default check by implementing `IEquatable<T>`.

Is there a better way then using an `unsafe` block and doing a byte-by-byte equality check?

Comment: I suspect the answer here is fundamentally "no, you'd have to do that"; you *can* probably do it without `unsafe` and unmanaged pointers, though, by using refs and spans; that doesn't gain a whole lot, though, other than avoiding the `unsafe` keyword :)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, probably it's a X Y problem.

Comment: With an addition to what @Marco Salerno said, your actual problem is likely the datatype you're trying to use. I'm pretty sure `default` is the type with all of its bits set to 0. So for an `int` this is going to be 0. However for `int?`, default is going to be null. It all depends on the behaviour you expect and want, compared to what datatypes you use.